# What kind of container should be used for storing a disassembled Cessna 172?

Tags: cessna-172, aircraft-storing

I need to store a damaged aircraft away rather than leave it exposed to the weather and elements on a tie-down at an airport. It is a Cessna 172. If I remove the wings and horizontal stabilizer (from the tail), I can fit all lengthwise into a 40 foot shipping container.

However the span of the landing gear is just over 8 feet and won't allow fitting width-wise into a standard container. I suppose the landing gear can also be removed, but not desirable. Are there extra-wide containers suitable for storing small aircraft?

Comment: How long of storage, and what kind of local weather are you facing? - Those details may impact people's answers. Also whether or not you can build a temp structure, or if it has to be some kind of Container like portable box.

Comment: @TheLuckless We are in the mid-Atlantic northeast so we are frequented by noreasters, snow, rain, hail, and the occasional hurricane (Sandy).  We have heavy bird and insect infestation, not to mention scavengers and theives.  My beacon is missing.  It will cost much money to repair the aircraft and make it airworthy again.  In the meantime, I figured a shipping container would shelter the aircraft and I can also put on a flatbed truck and transport to wherever location.  I am sure I am not exceptional in having this need.  Don't they have extra wide containers?

Comment: If it is *just* over 8 feet, you could try removing the tires.  And put it on some little dollies or something.

Comment: If the search for a wider container comes up dry, would it be possible to build a cradle that can hold the fuselage with enough roll on it to make the gear fit diagonally in the container?  If my math is right, there's something like 11' on the diagonal.

Comment: @0tyranny0poverty The point of having standard shipping containers is that they are *standard*. The height can vary within a certain range, but if the length* or width varied, they couldn't be stacked. (*Okay, there are two lengths, but one is exactly twice the other, so they're still stackable.)

Comment: Have you looked at the sort of shrink-wrap plastic that I see used for winter storage of boats?

Comment: Be sure to check whether "cost of storage + cost of repair" < "cost of selling as-is + cost of buying a replacement".  Sometimes the cheapest way to store a vehicle is to sell it then buy a new one later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A "dry van" (nonrefrigerated) 53 foot trailer, commonly towed as a "tractor trailer" sports an extra 3 inches of inside diameter (8 foot 3 inches) to go with 9 feet 3 inches in height.

You could also build a custom crate either onsite (storage shed) or portable (on a flatbed).
Transporting it to a local barn or unused building is also possible, better than leaving it to the elements.

I would look into local storage options, with the wing removed, there should be many.

Answer (score 1):

Finding a barn is better choice as it has a lot of space in it. You need an escort traffic police to close certain roads in order to tow the plane on a flat bed trailer truck to the barn. However, bear in mind, the cost of renting the barn is key to keeping it there. Otherwise, if it can sold away, you might as well do it, too. There is no point having a non-functional plane when it could be sold to another interested party for the safekeeping of it.